# Testing service call from my component unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, karma-jasmine

How would I simply test that my service is called?

myComp.ts

```
constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

myFunction() {
   this.myService.someFunction();
}
```

myTest.ts

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule, HttpClientModule],
      declarations: [MyComponent]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should delete customer feed', () => {
    const mySpy = spyOn(MyService, 'someFunction');

    component.myFunction();

    expect(mySpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
```

Currently the line `const mySpy = spyOn(MyService, 'someFunction');` shows red squigglies on `'someFunction'` stating:

> Argument of type 'someFunction' is not assignable to parameter of type prototype | service | url

**Update**
How my set up is now as per comments:

```
let myService: MyService;

beforeEach(() => {
  ...
  providers: [MyService],
  ...
  .compileComponents()
});

beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TesBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();

  myService = TestBed.get(MyService);
});
```

**Update (solution)**
I was still using the UPPERCASE MyService rather than the lowercase myService in my spy definition!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply go ahead and `spyOn` your service method to see if it was called.
You should mock the service and provide it to your component at the TestBedConfiguration.

You can mock all your service methods and return any value as needed to check if call was made to your service method.

```
 class MyServiceStub {
     constructor(){}

     myFunction() { returns Observable.of({});}

    }
 let myService;
    beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule, HttpClientModule],
       providers: [
                { provide: MyService, useValue: new MyServiceStub() }
            ],
            schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
      declarations: [MyComponent]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

   beforeEach(() => {
     fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
     component = fixture.componentInstance;
       fixture.detectChanges();
    myService = TestBed.get(MyService);
    });

  it('should delete customer feed', () => {
    const mySpy = spyOn(myService , 'someFunction');

    component.myFunction();

    expect(mySpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
   });
```

if you do not want to mock your service using a stub , just use `TestBed.get(MyService)` to get the service instance after you provide the service to your component in `TestBed.configureTestingModule`

Comment: If I were to go the route of `let myService = TestBed.get(MyService);`, would I make the `providers:`, `{provide: MyService, useValue: myService`?

Comment: In that case do not use `useValue`, just add your service to providers array: `providers: [ MyService]` and use the service from TestBed :  let myService = TestBed.get(MyService);

Comment: I am putting the `TestBed.get...` just below the `.compileComponents()`.

Comment: Also... Would I then need to do a `spyOn(MyService, 'someFunction')` in my test, as my main goal is to check that my service function is called....

Comment: Yes, You still need to spy the service to see if it was called, or look for the return from service method and verify. Yes, anytime after your TestBed is ready is good to grab service instance.

Comment: But I am still getting the red squigglies saying `Argument of type 'someFunction' is not assignable to parameter of type prototype | service | url` :-/

Comment: do you have MyService imported. You can also declare let myservice: MyService

Comment: Yes, I have actually done it this way. `let myService: MyService` and then within the `beforeEach` I included `providers: [MyService]` and then `myService = TestBed.get(MyService)`

Comment: I spotted my mistake, I was still using `MyService` instead of `myService` in my spy definition! Thank you for helping me set things up.